# Why do the Jedi cremate their fallen comrades?

Tags: star-wars

Obviously it's a ritual, but is there an objective to the ritual? Does it unite the dead, one with the force or allow some sort of metaphysical rebirth?

Comment: They taste better cooked.

Comment: No clear answer contained within, but you might find [this Wookiepedia Article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cremation) of value.

Comment: To prevent them from turning into Force-Zombies!

Comment: mmmm braaiiinnns *force pull*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-universe, it's an honorific ceremony, with the symbolism of the Jedi's body and mind becoming one with all things (the Force).

Out-of-universe, it's a common ritual among "warrior cultures" in human history; the Vikings most predominantly, but it's also traditional among the Japanese and other Asian cultures, which inspired the Jedi as "futuristic samurai". Zen Buddhism and related faiths probably inspired the meaning behind the Jedi funeral, and behind the Jedi's "religion" in general.

Comment: do you have any sources for that in-universe answer? if you do I will accept that answer.

Comment: @Jared the ceremony where Luke burns Anakin's body actually has extremely strong correspondences to a Hindu ceremony. I was just reading about this a few hours ago, but I can't find the source now

Answer (score 1):

Besides probable spiritual reasons, consider that Jedi are typically space-travelling people without a home. Thus, it does not make too much sense to bury them. Other than burning, what can you do (i.e. what has humanity come up with and would thusly be ok in a movie)?

Comment: I'd go with what they occasionally do in Star Trek:  Send the body into a nearby star.  Much more "one with the universe" than plain old cremation  ;)